# Responsive navigation menu with toggle

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, responsive-design, window-resize

I'm trying to finish my web project for the master I'm doing here in madrid at the moment, and I'm having a hard time accomplishing this.

You can have a look at the fool code on this site:

http://cice.digitalcore.es/febrero/majestic/

the code for the toggle is:

```
//Navigation Toggle
    function navToggle() {
        if(open){
            if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
                $("#navigation-panel").animate({width: "toggle"}, 500)
                $("#photos").animate({"margin-left":"310px"}, 500);
                open= false;
            }
            else if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
                $("#navigation-panel").animate({width: "toggle"}, 500)
                $("#photos").animate({"margin-left":"410px"}, 500);
                open= false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#navigation-panel").animate({width: "toggle"}, 500)
            $("#photos").animate({"margin-left":"10px"}, 500)
            open= true;
        }
    }
```

My primary problem is once the navigation is open at first everything is fine, but once a resize the window under 1024 or the other way round the image wall brakes, it doesn't respect the different margins assigned for resolutions under 1024 or over 1024.

I hope you can help me out i would appreciate it a lot :).

EDITED:

Ive tried this, but it doesn't work either:

```
$(window).resize(autoResize);

    //Auto Resize
    function autoResize() {
        if ($("#navigation-panel").is(":visible")) {
            if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
                $("#photos").animate({"margin-left":"310px"}, 500);
            }
            else if ($("#navigation-panel").is(":visible")) {
                if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
                    $("#photos").animate({"margin-left":"410px"}, 500);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks Easwee :) got to fix it adding this:

```
$(window).resize(autoResize);

    //Auto Resize
    function autoResize() {
        if ($("#navigation-panel").is(":visible")) {
            if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
                $("#photos").css({"margin-left":"310px"});
            }
            else if ($("#navigation-panel").is(":visible")) {
                if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
                    $("#photos").css({"margin-left":"410px"});
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

best regards,
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger the `navToggle()` function also on window resize.

Since I see you use jquery have a look at http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Cant quite figure out how to use it, any more advice? :)